# Treat nonexistent directory in URL as an invite code?

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have a situation where users will be assigned a randomly generated invite code to share. I would like to make it so that users can merely enter that invite code in the URL as a directory.

At present, I handle the invite code via GET:

`example.com/signup.php?i=iNviTe`

I would like to simplify this so that `example.com/iNviTe` will have the same result as the above URL, but be entirely transparent to the user.

This is as close as I have gotten to solving the URL rewrite aspect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /signup.php?I=$1 [L]
```

How is this feasible? The servers I am using run Nginx and Apache, respectively, and the site is written in PHP.

Comment: A user defined invite code? Then you need to validate it first if it's unique before allowing the user to invite.

Comment: I too am curious about this. @kimbarcelona, it's not user defined. It's meant to be a code which is unique to each user. So rather than having the user visit `example.com/join.php?ref=SomeUserId` it would be `example.com/SomeUserId`. The user ID is not selected by the user necessarily (although a username would be sufficient).

Comment: Thank you, Spencer; you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a joint effort between the web server and PHP. The web server needs to know to pass non-existent files/directories to a PHP script.

If you are using Apache, look into .htaccess and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html). An example ruleset would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*)$ /invite.php?code=$1 [L]
```

Where `$_GET['code']` will be set with the code provided in the URL. So visiting `example.com/foobar` will silently redirect to `example.com/invite.php?code=foobar`

Comment: From what I understand, that looks like it would work.  However, I needed to first get it setup for nginx.  This is what I managed to convert your answer to:

    
    `if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*)$ /invite.php?code=$1 break;
    }`

Since that seems to be working, I will give you credit.  Thank you, Fly.